# Finding If A Replacement Manufacturing Test System Fails More Units

Tags: statistical-significance

I'm currently writing software that replaces an existing legacy system, which tests units against different engineering specifications. Since I'm currently verifying everything works, and I was able to pull all data for all parts historically tested in the legacy system into my new database, I decided to run all units against their respective specifications (~780,000 units).

I took the results from the tests, and formatted them in a way for the engineering team to overview. The engineers became skeptical of my version of the software, claiming my system is failing too many units. From my limited testing, it's seemed as though the new and old software have been passing the same number of units.

I cannot do the same analysis with the legacy software, running it against all units to get an overall failure percentage. However, I can run small sample reports on my own time in the new and old system and compare the results for the same units.

If I am able to collect data on X units between each system, and gather the percentages that fail on the new and old system, what statistical test can I use to prove the data does not significantly differ, or does significantly differ from system to system?

I have experience with basic statistics classes, and I remember learning a similar problem, but I'm completely drawing a blank from my courses on what methodology I should be using for this type of sampling.

Comment: This question would be *much* more likely to be useful if you actually detained the statistical models and tests you are employing.

Comment: I'm by no means a statistician, I'm hoping for insight on what statistical models I can employ. If the answer ends up being that I just need to look into a specific field more, I accept that.

Comment: What do you data look like? What are the value your variables take. How are the data collected? What are the substantive questions you are trying to answer? What does "I decided to run all units" actually mean?

Comment: I will assume that your failure rate is low - say 0.04% - or 400 defects per million (DPM). So if you compared 10,000 units to the specifications, you would expect about 4 failures. If the old vs. new system differ on the number of failed units, why not just examine in detail the cause of the mismatch for the couple of mismatches? Could end up being a numerical precision / representation issue only. Otherwise, web search for "equivalence testing" for some background on one technique that might be useful.

Comment: A test of paired 0/1 data (each unit fails or it doesn't) would seem to be taking us toward McNemar's test. If there are groups or other predictors/explanatory variables it may be more complex.

Comment: Thanks, McNemar's seems to match what I'm looking for. @blackeneth The failure rates are much higher, closer to 30% of all units, which makes it difficult to test one by one. The test uses a levenberg-marquardt fit on a sample of data, and analyzes the fitted function. There's no way for me to verify implementations against the old code anymore, and there are slight variations in fitting ability. I'll use this to see if there's a significant difference between passed units. I hope this is also a clearer explanation for you Alexis, I was trying to include relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [McNemar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McNemar's_test) test allows you to compare the **accuracy** of your tests. This would be a first possibility. Nevertheless I see two difficulties you could be running into, and which are not entirely clear from your question:

1. How does your problem look like?. What is your approach to it?. 
   Since you are attempting to detect failures, you might need to apply novelty 
   detection.
2. Is accuracy the appropriate measure for your problem?. Like I said, McNemar compares accuracy. But maybe you are more interested on minimizing the false positive rate or the false negative rate.

Another (better) option to compare classifiers is the [ROC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) curve and [AUC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Area_under_the_curve) (area under the ROC curve).

Comment: Thanks, from what I'm reading this seems to answer my question. I'll look more into it.